# Reduce number of columns for small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table used just for tabular layout not tabular data & I am trying to make it responsive. As it's just for lay out, I want to have only 1 column in small devices, 2 columns in medium devices, where as originally my table has 4 columns like:
Original table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class = "table">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtFname"/><td>
            <td>Middle Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtMname"/><td>
            <td>Last Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtLname"/><td>
            <td>Date Of Birth: </br><input type="text" id= "txtDob"/><td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In small devices it should be like:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>First Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtFname"/><td></tr>
        <tr><td>Middle Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtMname"/><td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtLname"/><td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date Of Birth: </br><input type="text" id= "txtDob"/><td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

2 columns in medium devices
Is there any way out there to achieve this, please suggest. I know his can be achieved with , but can it be done with ?

Comment: You shouldn't use tables for the layout precisely for this reason.

Comment: Correct. But,I have tabular layout & need to make it responsive. So asking if there is a way out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist to use table's insted of div's, a easy solution for you is to to use `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` class like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive hidden-xs">
    <table class = "table">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtFname"/><td>
            <td>Middle Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtMname"/><td>
            <td>Last Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtLname"/><td>
            <td>Date Of Birth: </br><input type="text" id= "txtDob"/><td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="visible-xs">
    <table>
        <tr><td>First Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtFname"/><td></tr>
        <tr><td>Middle Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtMname"/><td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name: </br><input type="text" id= "txtLname"/><td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date Of Birth: </br><input type="text" id= "txtDob"/><td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This will show your first table on tablet/desktop and the second table on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

Using tables for layout is not such a good idea. You can get the behaviour you want in this case by using bootstrap's `row` and `col` classes:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      First Name: <br><input type="text" id= "txtFname"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      Middle Name: <br><input type="text" id= "txtMname"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      Last Name: <br><input type="text" id= "txtLname"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      Date Of Birth: <br><input type="text" id= "txtDob"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's a bootply example: http://www.bootply.com/pDHIPj3NJ3